# does htmlspecialchars escape javascript?

Tags: php, escaping

I've stumbled over this questions:

Do you guys know if the htmlspecialchars function also escapes javaScript from user input?

Thanks

Comment: Well, the function isn't called `jsspecialchars`, is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, to answer your question, it depends.  If you're doing:

```
<p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($userInput); ?></p>
```

Then they will not be able to inject scripts into your application.

**HOWEVER**:

If you're trying to do this:

```
<script>
    var foo = '<?php echo htmlspecialchars($userInput); ?>';
</script>
```

You are **not** safe.  See Rule #3 on [OWASP's XSS Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_JavaScript_Data_Values).

To protect that, you'd need to use a JS aware escaping function.  You could json encode it if you just need a string literal, but I would use [ESAPI](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-php/source/browse/trunk/src/codecs/JavaScriptCodec.php) for PHP to take care of this.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) the following characters are replaced:

> - `'&'` (ampersand) becomes `'&amp;'`
> - `'"'` (double quote) becomes `'&quot;'` when `ENT_NOQUOTES` is not set.
> - `"'"` (single quote) becomes `'&#039;'` only when `ENT_QUOTES` is set.
> - `'<'` (less than) becomes `'&lt;'`
> - '`>'` (greater than) becomes `'&gt;'`

So a `<script>` tag would be modified, but the Javascript inside may or may not be modified, depending on which characters it contains.

Answer (score 2):

The [PHP manual](http://uk.php.net/htmlspecialchars) tell you exactly what characters get changed by the function.

It doesn't care if the string you give it contains HTML or JS or something else. It just makes those translations on whatever string you give it.

Since HTML and JS use different escape characters, it makes arbitrary data "safe" for use in HTML, which includes making some JS safe for use in HTML.

e.g.

```
$js = "if (foo && bar) { return false; }"
echo "<button onclick='" . htmlspecialchars($js) . "'>click</button>"
```

Will output:

```
<button onclick='if (foo &amp;&amp; bar) { return false; }'>click</button>
```

Thus preventing the special meaning that `&` has in HTML from breaking the script.

It won't make a string safe to use in JavaScript though, since it doesn't touch characters such as `\` which have special meaning there.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it does. `<script>` is changed to `&lt;script&gt;`

Comment: That's not JavaScript. That's HTML.

Comment: @BoltClock: but script inside is "escaped" (not executed) too